# Entity Framework: Map output parameters from stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, entity-framework-4

I want to map stored procedure OUTPUT parameters to an entity.

e.g.,

`PROCEDURE ForExample

@ID int,

@LastUpdate datetime OUTPUT

AS

Update EntityTable Set LastUpdate = GETDATE() Where ID = @ID

Select @LastUpdate = LastUpdate From EntityTable Where ID = @ID`

I want to map the @LastUpdate output parameter to an entity property.

In the Stored Procedure Mapping dialog, the @LastUpdate parameter shows up as an InOut parameter (green arrows going both ways). Whether I map the parameter to a property or not, I get the same error:

> A mapping function binding specifies a function Model.Store.ForExample with an unsupported parameter: LastUpdate. Output parameters may only be mapped through the RowsAffectedParameter property. Use result bindings to return values from a function invocation.

I tried adding a manual binding for LastUpdate in the "Result Column Bindings" but that didn't work.

Is what I'm trying to do supported by EF 4 and if so how is it done?

Answer (score 1):

As it's said in the error text, "Output parameters may only be mapped through the RowsAffectedParameter property. Use result bindings to return values from a function invocation"

If you want your procedure to return some value, e.g. last update, it should return it via a result set. That means, your stored procedure should look like this:

```
PROCEDURE ForExample
@ID int,
AS
Update EntityTable Set LastUpdate = GETDATE() Where ID = @ID
/*return lastupdate in resultset*/
Select LastUpdate as LastUpdate From EntityTable Where ID = @ID
```

And than you should map your result set column to lastupdate property like this:
[image]

And stored procedure's output parameters can only be used for optimistic concurrency.

Comment: Are you aware of anything special that needs to be done for 'Result Column Bindings' to be populated? In my case, I get nothing to select, even though my SPROC returns a dataset

Comment: ^--> NVM. The Result Column Bindings will not have populated values: you ***must*** type them by hand. This is unfortunate since the SPROC must be mapped and if the output columns/type are set, it should be able to grab them automatically..

Answer (score 0):

Here is another aproach which uses code and not Designer:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/diego/archive/2012/01/10/how-to-execute-stored-procedures-sqlquery-in-the-dbcontext-api.aspx